# How to apply authentication to mongo cluster composed of container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, authentication, shared

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
8ed380b215fe        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:50001->27017/tcp   shard1svr1
854d9f579a87        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:40001->27017/tcp   cfgsvr1
7a7cad24246c        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:37017->27017/tcp   mongos
```

I have configured a mongo cluster as above. This is the docker-compose file used to create each.

```
mongos docker-compose.yaml

version: '3'

services:

  mongos:
    container_name: mongos
    image: mongo
    command: mongos --configdb cfgrs/192.168.0.3:40001 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --port 27017
    ports:
      - 37017:27017
```

```
config server docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'

services:

  cfgsvr1:
    container_name: cfgsvr1
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 40001:27017
    volumes:
      - cfgsvr1:/data/db

volumes:
  cfgsvr1: {}
```

```
shard server docker-compose.yaml

version: '3'

services:

  shard1svr1:
    container_name: shard1svr1
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --shardsvr --replSet shard1rs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 50001:27017
    volumes:
      - shard1svr1:/data/db

volumes:
  shard1svr1: {}
```

After creation, I created an admin account, created a specific db, and created a user in a specific db.

```
mongos> show dbs
EV           0.761GB
admin        0.000GB
config       0.001GB
elex         0.000GB
sampleData   0.507GB
sampleData2  0.003GB
mongos> show users
mongos> use admin
switched to db admin
mongos> show users
{
        "_id" : "admin.admin",
        "userId" : UUID("1b1e25ad-4c54-4110-bafc-cb9643963d11"),
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}

mongos> use elex
switched to db elex
mongos> show users
{
        "_id" : "elex.elex",
        "userId" : UUID("8bdba5c5-41fc-4342-a68e-f930134615e9"),
        "user" : "elex",
        "db" : "elex",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "elex"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
```

However, you can access the db by simply url and port number without user id and pw from outside.

```
mongo "IP:PORT" -u admin -p "pass" --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Setting authenticationDatabase still doesn't take effect. How can I apply authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Typically users are created in 'admin' database, I don't know any useful reason to create them in another database.

In MongoDB you can connect even without authentication, however you cannot execute any command (apart from getting help and similar). If you try to query a collection for example then you will get an error "Not authenticated"

You need to enable authentication in config, have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

In a shared cluster you must also use internal authentication, in order to permit the host can communicate internally to each other, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/